# Запоминание в cookies выпадающего блока

Tags: jquery, php, cookie

Реализация выпадающего блока

```
<script>
function showhide(n)
{
    if(n==3)
    {
        for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
            document.getElementById('otd'+i).style.display='inline-block';

    }
    else
    {
      if (document.getElementById('otd'+n).style.display=='inline-block')
        document.getElementById('otd'+n).style.display='none';
      else
        document.getElementById('otd'+n).style.display='inline-block';
      }

}
</script>
```

Пример использования

---

```
echo '<a class="pointer cursor_pointer specialitys_seatch_head" onclick="return showhide(2);"><img src="/style/'.$setup['skin'].'/img/otdz.png" alt=""/></a>';
```

echo '<div id="otd2" class="hide">тут код</div>';

---

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при открытии блока он оставался открытым пока пользователь его не закроет.
Как такое можно реализовать? С использованием `cookies` или как-нибудь еще?

Answer (score 1):

Если после перезагрузки нужно это же состояние вернуть, то да - куки.

Если после релоада страницы не нужно, тогда можно использовать `$.data('.elem', 'data-id', 'data-info')`.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то я не увидел в твоём коде `Jquery`.

И зачем `php`? Через `js` тоже можно работать с `cookie` (это лезет в глаз метка `php`).

Полно примеров работы с `cookie`:

[через обычный `js`](http://clone.h16.ru/css-js/3/)

[`Jquery`](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/42.html)